# Vim command-line mode encoding error when using global search in autocmd

Tags: command-line, autocmd, encoding

**Update**
Found the issue due to souce the menu this cause `encoding=utf-8` and `fileencoding=cp936` in `_vimrc` but in `txt` files it shows `encoding=utf-8 fileencoding=utf-8`
The way to fix is reset `fenc=utf-8` after `source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim`
It worked

```
"condition setting {{{
if has("multi_byte")
" UTF-8 
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
set formatoptions+=mM
set fileencodings=utf8,ucs-bom,gbk,cp936,gb2312,gb18030
if v:lang =~? '^\(zh\)\|\(ja\)\|\(ko\)'
set ambiwidth=double
endif
if has("win64")
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
source  D:\Vim\function.vim
source  D:\Vim\PlugSetting.vim
"set menu "
set langmenu=zh_CN.UTF-8
set helplang=cn
language messages zh_CN.utf-8
set fenc=utf-8   " **<-- defined again here will keep enc and fenc all utf-8**
endif
```

---

**Background**

- Two kinds of characters in my TXT file, English and Chinese
  Both charcters are shows correct in gvim.
  Search and Substitute are correctly with mumanlly using
  `:g/\w\{4\}大` and `s/\w{4\}大`
- Error when using `autocmd` to execute the searching
  `au BufReadPost *.txt execute ' g/\w\{4\}大/ '`
  the seraching pattern Chinese character `大` seems with wrong encoding shows as `<b4><f3>`
  open the txt file shows `Pattern not found:\w\{4\}<b4><f3>`

**Question**
Why same command `:g/\w\{4\}大` have different encoding by manually typing and by executing in `autocmd` ?

---

I am writing a autocmd to dected `TXT` file and do some search
here's an simple case

```
aaaa大
bbbb
cccc大
dddd
```

the autocmd in my `_vimrc` is `au BufReadPost *.txt execute ' g/\w\{4\}大/ '`
then when I open a txt file it will shows the encoding error the final character `大`not shows correctly， it becomes`<b4><f3>`, here's the screen shot.

[image]

But, when i directly run the command in the txt file, it do worked:
[image]

This really fused me, i try and serach any way to fix this problem finally found the this character `大` encoding in autocmd is `encoding=cp936`, so i set a seperate encoding for the autocmd `au BufReadPost *.txt execute ' set enc=cp936|g/\w\{4\}大/ '` this will shows the correclt global search but! it will make the txt file wrong
I can see the global search cmd shows the correct character `大`， but the context in `TXT` shows not correctly.

[image]
[image]

My vim version 9.0, MS-Windows 64-bit GUI-console with OLE support.
My `encoding` in `_vimrc` is:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf8,ucs-bom,gbk,cp936,gb2312,gb18030
```

Why cause this problem, really confused

I am not sure how to shows the Chinese correctly both in file and when running `au BufReadPost *.txt execute 'g/\w\{4\}大/'`

Comment: you should never `change the encoding option of your running Vim`. That is strongely discouraged.

Comment: Hi,Chirs, I dont change the encoding but it really shows wrong character when runing autocmd

Comment: Using `:set encoding=cp936`  you are changing encoding. This makes all literal text stored inside Vims memory potentially invalid.

Comment: What is the encoding of your `_vimrc` file?

Comment: `大` is valid utf-8 so there is no need to change Vim's internal encoding or that of the `vimrc`. FWIW, I don't get errors with your command, here. Doing `:g/pat/` for the highlighting side-effect doesn't work, though, but that's another problem. You should probably use `:help :match` instead. Also note the part about the order of `ucs-bom` and `utf-8` in `:help 'fileencodings'`. It looks like you are trying things at random. https://i.imgur.com/zQ6Pdmr.png

Comment: `<b4><f3>` is not the UTF-8 byte sequence for 大; that would be `<e5><a4><a7>`. Neither is it the correct sequence in UTF-16; that would be `<59><27>` or `<27><59>`, depending on endianness. So most probably your .vimrc is stored in one of those Chinese encodings mentioned in your `fileencodings` option. You should either save your .vimrc with `fileencoding=utf8` or put a `scriptencoding` statement with the matching value at the start of your .vimrc.

Comment: hi @JürgenKrämer , the character `大` can be correctly shows in the file and i can do the global search `:g/\w\{4\}大/` manually, but it will something wrong when this command running in `autocmd `, I set fileencoding as `set fileencodings=utf8,ucs-bom,gbk,cp936,gb2312,gb18030`

Comment: `<b4><f3>` really seems to be the encoding for 大 in code page 936. (Tested by inserting 大 in an empty buffer, saving it with `:w ++enc=cp936 test.txt` and then dumping it with `xxd cp936` in a shell / command prompt.)

Comment: hi @JürgenKrämer , yes, I also try to use  `au BufReadPost *.txt execute ' set enc=cp936|g/\w\{4\}大/ '` to set a separate endcoding for this autocmd it will shows the correctly character `大` in command-line, but the file content will with wrong encoding.

Comment: I still think the encoding of your .vimrc is wrong. Open it in a new instance of Vim, check if 大 is displayed correctly, and execute `:set encoding? fileencoding?`. Put the value of `fileencoding` (if empty, the value of `encoding`) in a `scriptencoding` statement at the *start* of your .vimrc. If 大 is not displayed correctly, test if you can load it correctly with `:e ++enc=XXXX` (XXXX being one of the other encodings you have listed in your `fileencodings` option). Then use that encoding in the `scriptendoding` statement in your .vimrc.

Comment: Hi @JürgenKrämer , follow your steps I open a new file and type `大`，execute `:set encoding? fileencoding?` it shows `encding=utf-8 fileencoding=utf-8` , the character `大` also shows correctly. then `set scriptencoding utf-8` at the first line of `_vimrc` , but it still shows`<b4><f3>` in command-line mode message when using `autocmd`

Comment: @M_Sea I still think we have an XY problem here. Please clearly state what exact problem you want to solve with your `:g` command. What you showed here is most likely not the right solution to whatever issue you are facing!

Comment: Please show the encoding of your _vimrc, not the encoding of a new file with 大 in it and not the `set` statements for the different encoding options that you *use* in your _vimrc: first execute `:n $MYVIMRC` and then `:set encoding? fileencoding?`.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer it shows `encoding=utf-8 fileencoding=cp936` in `_vimrc`, but shows `encoding=utf-8 fileencoding=utf8` in all `TXT file` , they are different it's so weird

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I found the issue is source `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` to show the Chinese menue, the fixed way is `set fenc=utf-8` after this source, then both `encoding` and `fileencoding` will set as `utf-8`, the `autocmd` also behavior correct , Thanks so much

Comment: Glad you found *a* solution, though I doubt it should be *the* solution. Better save your _vimrc in utf-8 encoding and -- for safety -- put a `scriptencoding utf-8` at the start of it. (Actually I don't know if setting the *file* encoding inside _vimrc has -- or should have -- any effect.)

Comment: Maybe you could publish your own answer to the question and accept in two days using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `g/\w{4\}大` is an incomplete command (you lack the corresponding action)

If you would like initiate a search I would add the following line to your `_vimrc` instead:

```
au BufReadPost *.txt call setreg('/', '\w\{4\}大')
```

Comment: that is not true. By default, if no other action is given, `:g` will print the matching lines

Comment: I try this cmd `au BufReadPost *.txt call setreg('/', '\w\{4\}大')` but no effect in my *txt file

Comment: perhaps you should tell us, what you actually want to achieve instead? Why do you think you need such a `BufReadPost` autocommand?

Comment: Hi，@ChristianBrabandt,all my files are open with gvim ，only txt file I want to do the serach and replace with some patterns, this is why I use an `autocmd BufReadPost *.txt` ,but all chinese characters running in `autocmd` shows incorrectly.

Comment: for search and replace `:g` is the wrong command anyhow. Why do you want to perform a search and replace on **all** text files when loading your files. This will potentially corrupt your files without you even noticing. Please state in your question what exact problem you are facing.